# bootstrap 3 container-fluid columns don't align properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 **container-fluid** in which I have some columns that I want to get rid of the gutters and make the images stretch to 100% width.

Pretty straightforward by adding this css classes:

```
img {width:100%;}
.no-padding-left {padding-left:0px;}
.no-padding-right {padding-right:0px}
```

Now, the problem is that somehow on my last row the first column image doesn't stretch to 100% width.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYvr8/2/embedded/result/) to see exactly what I'm trying to say.

Any ideas how can I make the image on the left from the last row to stick to the one above it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add .no-padding-left on your second `.col-md-8` making the image below looking smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYvr8/3/embedded/result/